# Convert list with headers from horizontal to vertical

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I am trying to do is the following:

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/2qjxef9/9]

Answer (score 2):

Please try in A9:

```
=OFFSET($A$2,0,MOD(ROW()-1,4))
```

and in B9:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROW()-1)/4),MOD(ROW()-1,4))
```

then copy both down to suit.

[image: SO33967559 example]

Comment: This worked for me, except that in B9, the code =OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROW()-1)/4),MOD(ROW()-1,4)) was off by a row.  (Sorry...Didn't get that formatted right because I accidentally hit enter.)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been working on it... and my edit time ran out on that last comment.  For me, it showed row 3 very nicely, but then it skipped to row 5.  Am trying to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Found my error.  I placed my data starting in A1 and the question had the data starting in A2.  Move the range down one row and your code works perfectly.  Nice job.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Answer to Bill's "I'm still not able..."  Using punts code, and entering it directly into your image as he describes, the headers will be in column A and the data will be in column B, and all will be organized as described in your spreadsheet image. It is cool, and has many applications when working with two-dimensional ranges.

Comment: Well I got it for my test excel sheet. But my actual excel sheet has 80 rows 8 columns so its not working properly for that. Not sure what I need to change in the formula. First row is the column heads, next rows are the rates. So lets say it starts in row A1 to H1 are the headers

Comment: Sorry to be such a noob, you are great help pnuts!

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on what you are trying to accomplish, I notice that you have the headers repeated in rows. But you are also doing a transposition.  If you want each column to appear below the previous, try the solution provided by punts. However, if you want to simply transpose the range, consider either of the following.  1) copy.... past->transpose or 2) the transpose array function. For that, enter =TRANSPOSE(  and click on the hyperlink that should pop up.  Remember that an array function requires special steps when it is set up.  But once it is set up properly, it will update every time the sheet recalculates.

Comment: No, I didn't get from 'this' to 'to this'. That is the end result of what I need to get to. I made that as an example. But the entire excel file has 8 columns with 79 rows.

Comment: I didn't finish the 'to this' part. Obviously it would be longer, but was just showing it as the idea of what I need to get to.